# Is there a way to diff files from C++?

Tags: c++, c, diff, patch

I'm looking for a C or C++ diff library.  I know I can use the Unix `diff` tool in combination with `system` or `exec`, but I really want a library.  It would be handy if the library could perform patches as well, like the Unix `patch` tool.

Comment: It seems to me that a diff library would be pretty common, but Google has yet to turn up a good answer.

Comment: [An excellent approach was provided for C/C++ on a similar post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377443/diff-compare-two-files-by-file-descriptor-fd-instead-of-file-name/42380790#42380790)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think I've found a good solution, finally:

The [DTL - Diff Template Library](https://github.com/cubicdaiya/dtl) --- [Tutorial](https://github.com/cubicdaiya/dtl/wiki/Tutorial)

It supports patch.  I had to type "diff.cpp" into Google to find it.  Hopefully it works!

Answer (score 13):

It seems like the  [Google Diff, Match and Patch libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) are what you need.

Comment: Eh, but the C++ version of that library is dependent on Qt. I need a diff/patch library for a non-GUI application.

Comment: Qt has non-GUI parts, and can be used in a console application.

Comment: Qt is a large library dependency I don't want to have.  Why didn't the author use STL?

Comment: An STL port [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/leutloff/diff-match-patch-cpp-stl).

Comment: That's definitely better than DTL (which apparently does not offer a per-line diff algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/libmba/dl/src/diff.c) is an implementation of a "solution to SES/LCS with the Hirschberg linear space refinement as described in the following publication":

> E. Myers, ``An O(ND) Difference
>   Algorithm and Its Variations,''
>   Algorithmica 1, 2 (1986), 251-266.
>   http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/gene/PAPERS/diff.ps

Found it on the [Wikipedia page on diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).

That's only for finding a diff though, not applying it as a patch. I think that application of a patch is actually a harder problem; due to the risk of conflicts. It would need some form of user-controlling feedback mechanism, to resolve conflicts.

Comment: This is the best I answer so far, but I really would like a patch library as well.  I'll wait a little to see if anyone else has an answer.

Comment: The file `diff.c` linked at the beginning appears to have disappeared. (It is still in the Google index though...)

Comment: @unwind Oh my, I'm sorry. It is just the https transport that yields a 404 error. Disabling HTTPS Everywhere results in the file being loaded.

Answer (score 3):

There is one that is part of [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).  It exists as some C code that's designed as a Python extension, but it could probably be extracted pretty easily.  I believe it can also do binary diffs.

The relevant .c files are [mercurial/bdiff.c](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/tip/mercurial/bdiff.c), [mercurial/mpatch.c](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/tip/mercurial/mpatch.c) and possibly [mercurial/diffhelpers.c](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/tip/mercurial/diffhelpers.c).

Answer (score 2):

Subversion includes a library [`libsvn_diff`](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/subversion/libsvn_diff/).

Answer (score 1):

Also pretty much unfindable in Google, it turns out that Gnulib has a [diff module](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/diffseq.h;hb=HEAD). This one seems sufficient for what I wanted a diff library for. It doesn't seem to have a patch module, though.