# c++ line-based unified diff library

Tags: c++, diff

Does anyone know of a good c++ library that can provide a line-based unified diff?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to diff files from C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451694/is-there-a-way-to-diff-files-from-c)

Comment: @ergosys, google Bringed me to here because of the library component of the question. So answers are same but questions are different.

Comment: https://github.com/cubicdaiya/dtl

Answer (score 0):

How about the [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) library? Alternatively, you could just invoke the [diff utility](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/diff.html) from your code, using [popen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html), and then you could read the differencing output produced by the diff utility from the pipe.

Comment: google-diff-match-patch is character-based.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the svn sources contain a good differ